# how to understand the sentence "There are many advantages to hosting your own WordPress blog"

Tags: grammar

During my English lessons, I was confused by this sentence:

> There are many advantages to hosting your own WordPress blog.

It seems that in my memory, my English teacher told me that it was correct to use **to host** rather than **hosting** in this sentence, so is there anyone who can tell me how to correctly understand the grammar of this sentence?

Comment: Your English teacher was not a native speaker. The infinitive _to host_ is ungrammatical here. The reason is that _advantage_ requires a preposition _to_ (_What's the advantage to that?_), so that's not an infinitive marker. The proper complement after the preposition is a gerund, so _hosting_ is correct.

Comment: thanks,seems that I had been confused by this on my English learning for a long time!

Comment: While @JohnLawler has explained it correctly, I want to add a point which may explain what your teacher was saying (in case your reference was in general and not specifically about this particular sentence) :It is correct to say "there are many **ways to host** your blog" and it is incorrect to say "there are many **ways to hosting** your blog". If your teacher specifically used "advantages", then "hosting" is correct & "host" is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Though the word 'advantage' uses the preposition 'of' or 'over' more, the use of 'to' still makes sense.

I suggest you use 'of' in place 'to' :

There are many advantages of hosting your own WordPress blog.

However, your question is slightly different. Answering that I wouldn't use 'advantages to host', I would use 'advantages to/of hosting'.

Advantage to doing something means that you will be gaining something by doing it. I hope that answers your question.